# Binder - ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.X.X

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, android-binder

I came across an issue that while I was able to resolve, I believe would benefit this platform. I will therefore pose the question here and answer it.

When attempting to publish an app on binder, you are required to create a Requirements.txt file that outlines your dependencies. Mine was using pandas version 1.4.4. When attempting to launch binder using my GitHub repo, I was getting:

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.4.4

Comment: This is cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-binder-cant-find-any-libraries/5179/3?u=fomightez). Please don't cross-post without acknowledging that in **ALL** places. By not linking, you can get multiple people answering the same things and thus wasting multiple people's time. Additionally, it ends up isolating information. Others with the same issue may not find where the solution was noted. Keep in mind that the person you may be helping find the solution is the "future you" six months from now coming across the issue again and not recalling the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested I move some of my comments below my response to Hossam's answer to a proper answer. This is that:

Hossam had suggested adjusting the version of Pandas to match, but if you want a more recent version it is possible. Here the OP wanted Pandas 1.4.4.

It comes down to needing to make sure the version of Python matches the packages. I discuss what I think the issue was in detail [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-binder-cant-find-any-libraries/5179/4?u=fomightez). Pandas 1.4.4 says it needs Python 3.8 [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.4.4/); however, default (vanilla) mybinder session at the time were launching with Python 3.7 still.

If you find the version of Python currently served without specifying anything is too old, you can update it using settings in `runtime.txt` if using `requirements.txt` to specify packages (`pip`-based only) or in `environment.yml` if using that (primarily `conda`-based). [The documentation in the configuration files](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/config_files.html) covers this for the conda/envionrment.yml and [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) spells it out for the requirments.txt-based approach.